# Adding JFoenix JavaFX Element to FXML won't launch after compile

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, jfoenix

I am using Netbeans 8.2 and I am building a simple FXML project.

Starting from scratch and a fresh JavaFX FXML Application, Cleaning and Building works fine and Launching the example file from the /Dist/ Folder works perfect.

However,

The minute I add the JFoenix library and any JFoenix Elements to the FXML it will no longer launch after it is compiled, giving off the following.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/StyleConverterImpl
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton$StyleableProperties.<clinit>(JFXButton.java:196)
        at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton.<init>(JFXButton.java:156)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at javafxapplication3.JavaFXApplication3.start(JavaFXApplication3.java:22)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleConverterImpl
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 37 more
Exception running application javafxapplication3.JavaFXApplication3
```

However Launching in the NetBeans IDE works perfectly.

What is going on here? I can see that the LIB is correctly being added to the /dist/ folder.

Comment: This is definitly a Java 9 issue. Check for the jdk9 release or fall back to 8 if they don't have one.

Comment: I don't use JFoenix (I don't consider it to be production quality because of its lack of any real documentation), but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003684/errors-when-trying-to-use-jfxpasswordfield-jfoenix-java. It looks like you have mismatched versions (the version of JFoenix targeted for Java 8 will apparently not work on Java 9).

Comment: Hmm, I should be using Java 8 for everything at the moment. I will double check that.

Comment: You are definitely running this under Java 9.

Comment: @James_d really? I use JFoenix extensivelly and my clients are very happy. But i agree on bad docs, had to do alot of source code lookups on Github.

Comment: @James_D You're absolutely right, I just did a Java -version and my desktop is running 9 but my IDE is running 8... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@james_d, Noticed I was running java 9 on my desktop but was running java 8 on the IDE.

Which explains my issues.